# rails s時にAddress already in useと言われるが、lsofでは使用中ポートに表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

現在、DockerCompose+Rails+pumaでローカル開発環境を構築しています。
その際にDocker内でrails sを実行すると

```
root@e455bb5e4d41:/home# rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.5-p157), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
~~~~
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

というエラーが出ます。
そこで、使用ポートを調べる為に

```
root@e455bb5e4d41:/home# lsof -i
```

を実行した所、何も表示されませんでした。
何故この様なエラーになるのでしょうか？ご回答いただけると助かります。

以下に関係あるかわかりませんが、dockerのpsとpumaのコンフィグを書かせていただきます。

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e455bb5e4d41        hoge   "irb"               13 hours ago        Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   hoge
```

config/puma/development.rb

```
port        3000

environment "development"

plugin :tmp_restart

bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'

daemonize false
```

Comment: `lsof -i :3000`でポート番号を指定した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。```root@541d5008edc4:/home/# lsof -i:3000```を実行しましたが、何も表示されませんでした。

Comment: `rails s -p 3001`とかで、別ポートでは立ち上がりますか？、Apacheが`Listen 3000`している例とかありましたけど……https://qiita.com/pugiemonn/items/06aec9741c7feed0cc0e

Comment: すみません、自己解決しました。お手数を掛けて申し訳ありませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すみません、自己解決しました。
pumaの`port 3000`と`bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'`を２重に記述していた為でした。
申し訳ありませんでした。